# MS Access multivalued field query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, multivalue

MS Access Database 2010, following tables are created:

BazaNalaza columns:

- ID -  autonumber
- ReportID - number
- ResponsibleUnit - number, multivalued field, linked to ResponsibleUnits table

ResponsibleUnits:

- ID - autonumber
- Name - text
- CompanyLine - text

ResponsibleUnits contains following data:

```
ID  + Name      + CompanyLine
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1   + ItOps     + Technology
2   + IdDev     + Technology
3   + CRM       + Marketing
4   + Legal     + ExCo
5   + ItDWH     + Technology
```

Following SQL query is working fine:

```
SELECT * FROM BazaNalaza
WHERE BazaNalaza.ResponsibleUnit.Value IN (1,2,5)
```

However, following code is NOT working:

```
SELECT * FROM BazaNalaza
WHERE BazaNalaza.ResponsibleUnit.Value IN (SELECT ID FROM ResponsibleUnits WHERE CompanyLine = "Technology")
```

Second query works only for the lines where values within bazaNalaza.ResponsibleUnit begins with 1, 2 or 5, while fields which contains e.g. (3,5) or (4,5) or (3,4,5) are not in the resultset.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend just do not use multivalued fields, they are still buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Queries with multi-value lookup fields can be a bit strange because the context of a given table can sometimes be at the "parent" level and sometimes be at the "child" level. However, this seems to work for your case:

```sql
SELECT b.* FROM BazaNalaza b
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT ID, ResponsibleUnit.Value FROM BazaNalaza
        WHERE 
            ID=b.ID 
            AND
            ResponsibleUnit.Value IN (
                SELECT ID FROM ResponsibleUnits 
                WHERE CompanyLine = "Technology"
            )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you Gord Thompson! After two days of careful testing, I can confirm that this solution is correct and working!

Answer (score 0):

You really should not have multivalued attributes. It's violating first normal form.

This format won't work and you'll probably need another table to separate that column from BazaNalaza table.

try this

```
select disinct * from BazaNalaza inner join ResponsibleUnits on ResponsibleUnits.ID = BazaNalaza.ResponsibleUnit.Value
```

Comment: Yes I know, but the application is inherited and need a quick solution (if exists). Also, database is full of tables with multivalued fields so re-engineering will take weeks :(

Comment: second query doesn't return results at all when 3 , 4 , or 5 is in the result set? what does that mean? works for me when i create tables like yours

Comment: first query is working fine. Second is not working. E.g., when you have following lines within BazaNalaza:
1; 1; (1,2)
2; 1; (1,3)
3; 2; (3,4,5)
4; 1; (3,4)
5; 6; (5)
6; 3; (4,5)

first query will  return lines 1,2,3,5 and 6, while second will miss lines 3 and 6. It looks like that only first value from multivalued field is used for comparison?

Comment: why is it stored as (1,2) 2 in that column? should it just not be 1, 2?

Comment: It is 1,2 I just used parenthesis to emphasis multivalued field, sorry for unclear comment.

Comment: i edited answer; it had to do with making sure the multivalued attribute gets expanded to each record. including it in select or join does it but not in where